# Raspberry Pi / Python code runs as expected through terminal, does not run the same at boot through crontab

Tags: python, cron, raspbian

I am admittedly quite new to much of this, from linux and python to electronics and the rasberry pi.. the system it is a raspberry pi running latest rasbian os, booting to LXDE.

I have a fairly simple bit of python code that checks status of three services, apache2, mysql, and vsftpd and will signal to turn on/off a bicolored red/green LED. I added a little more to make all three lights blink yellow for a couple seconds before the service check. Code is below:

```
    import os, time, subprocess
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(7, False)
    GPIO.output(11, False)

    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(12, False)
    GPIO.output(16, False)

    GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(18, False)
    GPIO.output(22, False)

    def LED_G():
        GPIO.output(11, True)
        GPIO.output(16, True)
        GPIO.output(22, True)
        GPIO.output(7, False)
        GPIO.output(12, False)
        GPIO.output(18, False)

    def LED_R():
        GPIO.output(11, False)
        GPIO.output(16, False)
        GPIO.output(22, False)
        GPIO.output(7, True)
        GPIO.output(12, True)
        GPIO.output(18, True)
    def LED_Y():
        GPIO.output(11, False)
        GPIO.output(16, False)
        GPIO.output(22, False)
        GPIO.output(7, False)
        GPIO.output(12, False)
        GPIO.output(18, False)

    def LED_OFF():
        GPIO.output(11, True)
        GPIO.output(16, True)
        GPIO.output(22, True)
        GPIO.output(7,  True)
        GPIO.output(12, True)
        GPIO.output(18, True)

    def initializeLED():
        for x in range(0,8):
            LED_Y()
            time.sleep(.100)
            LED_OFF()
            time.sleep(.100)

    def is_service_running(name):
        with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
            exit_code = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=hide_output, stderr=hide_output).wait()
            return exit_code == 0

    def set_status_LED():
        if not is_service_running('apache2'):
            GPIO.output(12, False) #Red ON
            GPIO.output(16, True)  #Green OFF
        else:
            GPIO.output(12, True)  #Red OFF
            GPIO.output(16, False) #Green ON

        if not is_service_running('mysql'):
            GPIO.output(18, False) #Red ON
            GPIO.output(22, True)  #Green OFF
        else:
            GPIO.output(18, True)  #Red OFF
            GPIO.output(22, False) #Green ON

        if not is_service_running('vsftpd'):
            GPIO.output(7,  False) #Red ON
            GPIO.output(11, True)  #Green OFF
        else:
            GPIO.output(7,  True)  #Red OFF
            GPIO.output(11, False) #Green ON

    initializeLED()
    while True:
        set_status_LED()
```

When I run the code in terminal `python service_status_led.py` or `python service_status_led.py &` everything functions as expected. lights flash yellow and ultimiately turn red or green. the check status function runs in an infinite loop so if a service goes down the light will change accordingly.

I did a `cp service_status_led.py /bin/` and then `sudo crontab -e` added `@reboot python /bin/service_status_led.py` (also have done with `&`).. reboot the system and the LEDs start to to the initial blinking but will not go to the next step of the infinite system check.. i have changed the sequence of the 'initializeLED' function and have discovered that whatever color that function ends with, red, green, yellow, or off, is how the lights will appear. it seems to not enter into the loop. I tried to remove the loop and just do a single check after the initialize sequence but it will not do that either.

Ive been searching for quite a bit to solve this issue and cant quite find a solution, sorry if this has been asked before

-- Update:
As per Klaus D.'s suggestion, I dropped the crontab and went about it with systemd. As I stated in the comments it worked initially and upon reboot did not. Spent some time digging around, trying this and that. Ultimately through `journalctl` I was able to discover that the errors were with my `myservice.service` file, the `WorkingDirectory` and `ExecStart`.

from:

```
    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u main.py
    WorkingDirectory=/custom/LEDSS
```

to:

```
    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /custom/LEDSS/service_status_led.py
```

One other thing I did was ensure permissions on the `.service` file were correct. Im not sure if they werent correct before but set `chmod 644 myfile.service` as well as the above change to the file itself.

Everything is in working order! Found my result at: https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/

Klaus, appreciate the help in steering me in the right direction.

Comment: 1. Code in an endless loop is not suited for cron. 2. It you run in an endless loop you should add some sleep time to prevent full CPU usage.

Comment: tbh there was sleep time, i edited it out for the sake of things `starttime = time.time()` `time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime ) % 60.0))`. with or without sleep time it doesnt get to the loop. also, i was not aware of that.. what would be better suited for my purpose?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md

Comment: I tried setting it up as a service, named it `ledstatus.service` and it worked for a short period of time. after creating the .service file with the info and pathing to my .py i tried using `systemctl start ledstatus.service` and the lights blink up and turn green. i stopped and started the apache2 service, lights reacted.. `systemctl enable ledstatus.service` `systemctl reboot -i` does not start at boot. well, it _does_ start but into a failed status.  `systemctl status ledstatus.service` returns `(code=exited, status=210/CHROOT)`